# Whitelisting domains for LinkedIn AutoFill button

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to set up the LinkedIn Autofill button on a client's website, as explained on this page.

Step 4. says to send my LinkedIn representative a list of domains and subdomains where I will be placing the AutoFill code to whitelist your domains. I asked my client to take care of it, so they asked their LinkedIn representative, who said I should contact a LinkedIn developer by posting a message here and tagging it with "linkedin".

Thanks in advance for your help.